# Using Node.js with CouchCMS

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

I would like to use the features of Grunt and Gulp (preprocessing, compressing, watching etc.), but I don't want to abandon traditional PHP. I use CouchCMS which requires traditional PHP.

Can I use both CouchCMS with Grunt or Gulp? If not, why is that so, and is there any viable alternative?

Thanks

Comment: Your question doesn't really fit the standards for this site.   I suggest you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Dude... You need to be a bit more specific...

Comment: I deleted the first part, to make my question be more specific. To avoid any confusion, this is my question:
"Can I use both CouchCMS with Grunt or Gulp? If not, why is that so?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create `Gruntfile.js` in your core folder with configs and run it from same folder where your project located by `grunt <command>`. To install grunt as application, you need to install `node` and `npm` and then by using `npm`(Node Packaged Modules) you can install `grunt`/`gulp` via `npm install -g grunt` or `npm install -g gulp`. By adding `-g` property, you force installing packages inside your execution folder `bin` and you can use those packages as standalone console application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I might be wrong (which I probably am), as I am pretty new to node.js, but I think what you're explaining here is how to set Grunt up. I'm actually just looking to know if I can use traditional PHP, since the only feature I really want out of node.js is Grunt. Sorry, I'm having a hard time figuring out this Node.js stuff.

Comment: @Thegusse `Grunt` is `JavaScript` application, it can't be launched with `php`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a task runner for PHP you can use robo.li instead of Grunt, since grunt is meant for js.